# AngularJs Binding directives to getter properties

Tags: data-binding, angularjs

Are you able to bind a directive to a getter property on a service using AngularJs?

I have a directive that is trying to watch a property on a service, it gets updated once on app start. Then it never updates, even when the watched property updates.

Here is my directive:

```
authorization.directive("authorization", ["$rootScope", "authenticationService", "authorizationService", function ($rootScope, authenticationService, authorizationService) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var prevDisp = element.css("display");

        function update(user) {
            if (!authorizationService.isAuthorized(attrs.authorization, user)) { element.css("display", "none"); }
            else { element.css("display", prevDisp); }
        }

        scope.$watch(authenticationService.user, function () { update(authenticationService.user); });
    }
};
```

} ]);

Here is a cutdown version of my service:

```
App.factory("authenticationService", function ($http, $location) {
var _user = { email: null, ...... };

return {
    get user() { return _user; }, //This is the property I am trying to bind too
    login: function () { do stuff },
    logout: function () { do other things }
}
```

});

Comment: Have you tried using the third parameter to `$watch()`? Pass true as a third parameter and then check if your `$watch()` is triggered or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either watch an actual function (that's a callable thing) or a string that's going to be `$eval`-ed in the scope's context. Not a getter, which will just return the object.

Try with

```
scope.$watch(function () { return authenticationService.user; },
             function () { update(authenticationService.user); },
             true); // use true to check for differences in object's properties.
```

Answer (score -1):

`$watch`evalates functions or expressions, and in case of expressiones, there are evaluated against the current scope. If you are going to watch a variable, make sure it is attached to the scope first:

```
scope.user = authenticationService.user
scope.$watch('user', function (user, old) { update(user); });
```

Comment: This won't work - it will only add the value of the getter to the scope, not the getter itself.